# Is there a way to tell if a class was compiled for java6?

Tags: java, class, compatibility, java-6

How can I do to tell if a java class was compiled for use on a java 6 vm?

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the [class file format specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html). The [WP article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28file_format%29) includes the current set of version number constants.

Comment: I was looking more for something like a command, or just by looking at a header of the file or something like that.
But your answer is the closest to what I was looking for so far.

Comment: `javap -verbose -classpath ... com.company.YourClassName` will print out the version numbers for you

Comment: since matt b didn't make that an actual answer, and no one gave the magic number (50), I added an answer of my own, and made it a little easier to just get a yes/no answer.

Answer (score 4):

In unix,

```
$ javap -classpath <classpath> -verbose foo.Bar \
  | grep -q 'major version: 50' && echo yep || echo nope
```

thanks @matt b.

Answer (score 0):

By using a [java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: ... that doesn't go well, at least not with jd-gui. This one doesn't offer a view on a class file's metadata. (quickly tested with the actual V0.3.2). So with this method you'd have to look for the use of classes/methods that haven't been available until Java 1.6.

Comment: Inexact Andreas_D, the version of the compiler is displayed by JD-GUI:
drag and drop a class file and move the mouse over the tab.